# Configuring Terminal Emulator in PyCharm for ipython

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having some trouble configuring my terminal emulator in PyCharm (I'm also just getting started with Python, so forgive me). On my actual terminal, the ipython command works fine. However, within PyCharm's emulator, I get an error. I am using Anaconda and Python 3.8.3. Thank you!

```
(Homework1) Ks-MacBook-Pro:Homework1 user$ ipython
bash: ipython: command not found
```

Note: I do seem to have a working configuration for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. One needs to install the ipython package for the interpreter.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000512790-iPython-instead-of-Python-for-console-